# Java Memory Usage, many contradictory numbers

Tags: memory, java-8, playframework-2.5

I am running multiple instances of a java web app (Play Framework).
The longer the web apps run, the less memory is available until I restart the web apps. Sometimes I get an OutOfMemory Exception.
I am trying to find the problem, but I get a lot of contradictory infos, so I am having trouble finding the source.

This are the infos:

- Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS with 12 GB of RAM
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-8u111-b14-3~14.04.1-b14)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)

EDIT: 
Here are the JVM settings:

- -Xms64M
- -Xmx128m
- -server
- (I am not 100% sure if these parameters are passed correctly to the JVM since I am using an /etc/init.d script with `start-stop-daemon` which starts the play framework script, which starts the JVM)

This is, how I use it:

```
start() {
    echo -n "Starting MyApp"
    sudo start-stop-daemon --background --start  \
        --pidfile ${APPLICATION_PATH}/RUNNING_PID  \
        --chdir ${APPLICATION_PATH}  \
        --exec ${APPLICATION_PATH}/bin/myapp  \
        -- \
        -Dinstance.name=${NAME} \
        -Ddatabase.name=${DATABASE} \
        -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 \
        -Dsun.jnu.encoding=utf-8 \
        -Duser.country=DE \
        -Duser.language=de \
        -Dhttp.port=${PORT} \
        -J-Xms64M \
        -J-Xmx128m \
        -J-server \
        -J-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError \
        >> \
        $LOGFILE 2>&1
```

I am picking on instance of the web apps now:

`htop` shows 4615M of `VIRT` and 338M of `RES`.

When I create a heap dump with `jmap -dump:live,format=b,file=mydump.dump <mypid>` the file has only about 50MB.

When I open it in Eclipse MAT the overview shows "20.1MB" of used memory (with the "Keep unreachable objects" option set to ON).

So how can 338MB shown in htop shrink to 20.1MB in Eclipse MAT?

I don't think this is GC related, because it doesn't matter how long I wait, htop always shows about this amount of memory, it never goes down.

In fact, I would assume that my simple app does not use more then 20MB, mabye 30MB.

I compared to heap dumps with a age difference of 4 hours with Eclipse MAT and I don't see any significant increase in objects.

PS: I added the `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` option, but I have to wait for 5-7 days until it happens again. I hope to find the problem earlier with you helping me interpreting my numbers.

Thank you,
schube

Comment: Add the parameters of your JVM to the question. Stack memory allocation (-Xss), initial heap size (-Xms), max heap size (-Xmx), etc. Keep in mind that the total memory of a Java process is comprised of more than just its heap size. Also, you don't have to wait a few days for the JVM to crash on OutOfMemoryError - just decrease the heap size and it should happen faster. Then look at the stack trace as it might give you clues as of where exactly in the code an allocation failed.

Comment: Did you try to use a tool like JVisualVM to watch the changes live? Which part of memory within the VM keeps increasing?

Comment: Thanks! I added the JVM parameters. Yes, I can provoke an OutOfMemory Error earlier, you are right. But if possible, I want to find the problem before it occures. I cannot use JVisualVM since this is a remote machine. Thanks for all the input!!

Comment: @schube jvisualvm can connect to a remote host. It also opens heap dumps generated automatically (-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError) or using the jmap command.

Comment: Today, I connected to the remote host with VisualVM. I can confirm, that my JVM params are passed correctly to the JVM. Also, the heap has the max size expected. The metaspace is 99% used. Is this my problem? See here: http://imgur.com/a/sCGgw  HTOP still shows 380MB RES. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, the first screenshot says "JVM Flags: <none>" so -Xmx and -Xms are not passed I guess.

Answer (score 4):

The heap is the memory containing Java objects. `htop` surely doesn’t know about the heap. Among the things that contribute to the used memory, as reported by `VIRT` are

- The JVM’s own code and that of the required libraries
- The byte code and meta information of the loaded classes
- The JIT compiled code of frequently used methods
- I/O buffers
- thread stacks
- memory allocated for the heap, but currently not containing live objects

When you dump the heap, it will contain live Java objects, plus meta information allowing to understand the content, like class and field names. When a tool calculates the used heap, it will incorporate the objects only. So it will naturally be smaller than the heap dump file size. Also, this used memory often does not contain the unusable memory due to padding/alignment, further, the tools sometimes assume the wrong pointer size, as the relevant information (32 bit architecture vs 64 bit architecture vs compressed oops) is not available in the heap dump. These errors may sum up.

Note that there might be other reasons for an `OutOfMemoryError` than having too much objects in the heap. E.g. there might be too much meta information, due to a memory leak combined with dynamic class loading or too many native I/O buffers…

Comment: You are right, the JVM also loads stuff. But somewhere on the Play Framework website they wrote, that their website runs on a server with very little RAM (it was 64MB to 72MB as far as I can remember, I cannot find the link currently). My app is much smaller and needs so much more memory. There must be some problem I want to find!

Comment: Did they really claim to have a running server with that little *RAM* or did say that say that they run the server with that *heap size*? Trying to run a recent Java VM with only 72MB RAM would require a lot of tuning, even for a helloworld, and then, there is an operating system underneath that has to run somehow…